# roboelectric Test failing for Place Autocomplete Adapter on Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Tags: android, robolectric

I am writing test case for my `SearchFragment` which has a `AutoCompleteTextView seachAutoComplete`. `seachAutoComplete` uses  `PlaceAutocompleteAdapter extends : BaseAdapter() implements Filterable` (just like [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java)) to show result.

I am testing it like this in roboelectric

```
@Test
public void testAutosuggestAdaptor() {
    SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
    startFragment(fragment);
    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar = 
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.location_auto_fill_edit_Text);
    searchBar.setText("hsr");
}
```

But my test case fails on `Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`
giving an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not be called on the main application thread
```

Comment: you need to call your thread from main UI ?

Comment: @duggu Sorry!! I Did not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for Robolectric, the `Filter` is run on the main thread (see `ShadowFilter`). As a workaround, you can add a check for whether or not the task is completed before awaiting a result. For instance, instead of:

```
ResultType resultData = Tasks.await(task, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Use something like:

```
ResultType resultData;
try {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        resultData = task.getResult();
    } else {
        resultData = Tasks.await(task, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException
        | RuntimeExecutionException
        | CancellationException
        | ExecutionException
        | TimeoutException ex) {
    // handle error case
}
```

Assuming you're using something like `Tasks.forResult()` in your test case, the `Task` will already be completed, so `Tasks.await()` will never be called when running from the test. It's still safe to use it this way, you just likely will never hit the first case in the real world.